# Can I Set The Value Of A Text Input Field Using A Variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having one form. I am submitting the values to database of table test fields something .I want to fetch those existing values to text field so that I can edit and update again.

I am using below code but I am not getting valid output.

Can anyone help thanks in advance.

```
//these values iam passing from one form
$bre=$_POST['bf'];
$bres=$_POST['bs'];
$bree=$_POST['be'];
$lun=$_POST['lu'];
$luns=$_POST['ls'];
$lune=$_POST['le'];
$dinn=$_POST['din'];
$dins=$_POST['sd'];
$dine=$_POST['se'];

echo $bre;
echo $bres;
echo $bree;
echo $lun;
echo $luns;
echo $lune;
echo $dinn;
echo $dins;
echo $dine;


echo "<table width=791 border=1><tr><td width=243>Breakfast<input type=text name=bfh value= $bre></td>
<td width=239>Stat Time<input type=hidden name=bsh value=$bres/>
        </td>
    <td width=244>
      End Time
        <input type=text name=beh value=$bree />
          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lunch
        <input type=hidden name=luh value=$lun />
          </td>
    <td>Stat Time

      <input type=hidden name=lsh value=$luns/>
      </td>
    <td>End Time

      <input type=hidden name=leh value=$lune/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dinner
      <input type=hidden name=dinh value=$dinn/></td>
    <td>Stat Time
      <input type=hidden name=sdh value=$dins/></td>
    <td>End Time
      <input type=hidden name=seh value=$dine/></td>
  </tr>

</table>";
```

Comment: @Lavanya: please accept answers from your previous question, + please format your question properly...

Comment: You will get more answers if you accept your many previous questions

Answer (score 1):

You did not escape your input properly. Use the function [`htmlentities`](http://de.php.net/htmlentities) on *every* variable that is displayed on the HTML page. Otherwise you might get invalid text (as you’ve noticed) or worse, a big security hole, because a malicious user can enter arbitrary HTML/JavaScript combinations that will be included in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around the values of the attributes on the input-elements.

I would recommend using a html validator to find such issues.

You can also print out each variable initially with

`print_r($_REQUEST);`

to be sure they enter the script ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type=text name=beh value=$bree />
```

also this would be better like this

```
<input type='text' name='beh' value='{$bree}' />
```

you have to put `'` or `"` for each HTML attributes, and putting php replaces between `{}` would help you to see what is replaced PHP and would help if you access a variable in an object i.e. `{$foobar->bar}`

also like noted on other answer you have to use [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) the HTML is escaped properly.

Also your input are inside a `<form>` tag ? your table should be around a tag like that

`<form method="POST">`